# Listen for system menu on Android

Tags: java, android, menu

I am developing an android game, and I would like to pause the game when the user brings up the system menu (not sure of the official name, but its located on the bottom bar and it brings up time, date, wifi status etc when pressed). Is there any way to listen for this menu being opened?

What the menu looks like (right side of screen):

[image: System Menu]

Comment: Have a look at `onPause()` and `onStop()` - these method should be called when the user hits any button that sends your app to the background.

Comment: I already am using `onPause()`, I'll have a look at `onStop()` and see if that works. EDIT: `onStop()` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with: `onWindowFocusChanged()`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I am the original poster, and I just wanted people to know that I found a solution.